# outer measure and determining measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $\mu^*(E)$ as the number of points in $E$ if $E$ is finite and $\mu^*(E)= \infty$ if $E$ is infinite. Show that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure and determine the measurable sets.

Please give me a hint about this problem, specially the part that says "determine the measurable sets".

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $\mu^{\star}$ is indeed an outer measure.

Set $E$ is by definition $\mu^{\star}$-measurable if for each set $A\subseteq\Omega$: $$\mu^{\star}A\geq\mu^{\star}\left(A\cap E\right)+\mu^{\star}\left(A\cap E^{c}\right)\tag1$$

This is evidently true for each infinite $A$ (then $\mu^{\star}A=\infty$).

If $A$ is finite then also $A\cap E$ and $A\cap E^{c}$ are finite.

Finite sets are sent to their cardinality so again (1) is evidently
true.

So we conclude that **every** set $E$ is $\mu^{\star}$-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is infinite, can both $A\cap E$ and $A\cap E^c$ be finite? And what can you say about $A\cap E$ and $A\cap E^c$ when $A$ is finite?